# Reset value of a method in another controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Is there a way I can change the value of isClicked for the ReviewsController once the logout page has redirected a user to the Home.cshtml page in Views/Home/ ?

I have a method in a controller called reviews which sets IsClicked bool to true after a button is clicked only when the user is logged in.

I also have this method for index (Views/Reviews/Index.cshtml) within the ReviewsController which resets the IsClicked value to false when an unauthenticated user visits that page:

```
// GET: Reviews
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var results = await _context.Reviews.ToListAsync();

    //Check Authentication
    foreach (Reviews reviews in results)
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            reviews.IsClicked = false;
            _context.Update(reviews);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    return View(await _context.Reviews.ToListAsync());
}
```

If the user logs out from that page they will be redirected to the Home.cshtml (Views/Home/).

However, if the user logs back in from the Home.cshtml page then afterwards clicks on the Index.cshtml page(Views/Reviews) the value will not reset back to false since they have already reauthenticated themselves before visiting that page as an unauthenticated user.

A solution is to redirect the action method from the logout account controller to the Index.cshtml page however I do not want to do this.

Any ideas?